# Counting Sort My input is 1,4,3,1 But output is garbage value,1,1,3 Input is not not correct

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting, counting

```
#include<stdio.h>            
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int A[200],p=0,r=0,s=0,i,n,temp=0,B[200];  
    printf("Enter no. of Element for counting sort :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&A[i]);

    printf("\nBefore Sorting: ");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",A[i]);

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(A[i]>temp)
            temp=A[i];
    }

    printf("\nLargest %d \n",temp);

    counting_sort(A,B,n,temp);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",B[i]);

    printf("\n");
}


counting_sort(int A[],int B[],int n,int temp)
{
    int i=0,C[200],j;
    for(i=0;i<=temp;i++)
        C[i]=0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        C[A[i]]=C[A[i]]+1;

    for(i=1;i<=temp;i++)
        C[i]=C[i]+C[i-1];

    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        B[C[A[i]]]=A[i];
        C[A[i]]=C[A[i]]-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack overflow is not a debug tool. Use a debugger...

Comment: Whatever its purpose, `C[A[i]]=C[A[i]]-1;` is decrementing a value that will later be used as an array index in the same loop.

Comment: Flagged as "Off topic".

Comment: Sometimes SO is a debugger, but in this case I agree with @shapiroyaacov . OP would learn more from firing up their IDE's debugger and walking through this themselves.

Comment: C != C++. You should generally only tag the language you are compiling/writing.

Comment: Why bother with turning the count into prefix sums before storing to B?  Drop the `C[i] += C[i-1]` loop entirely, and then just use a nested loop to write `i` repeated `C[i]` times into `B[pos]`.  Local variables would make this a lot easier to read than array references all over the place, and maybe compile to better code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, pencil-and-paper time. Your input is:

```
A = {1, 4, 3, 1}
```

Your counts are determined correctly:

```
C' = {0, 2, 0, 1, 1}
```

You then turn this into accumulated counts:

```
C = {0, 2, 2, 3, 4}
```

This step is also correct. What does this array represent? For each element `a` in `A`, `C[a]` is the index of the element after all `a`s in the sorted array, `B`:

```
i      0   1   2   3    4
B[i]   1   1   3   4    <
```

The same is true for the elements not in `A`: `C[2]` is 2. There is an (imaginary) block of zero twos after the ones the index after that block is 2.

Because the index is the index after the block, you must decrement your index before you use it:

```
for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] - 1;
    B[C[A[i]]] = A[i];
}
```

Otherwise, you will write to index 4 eventually, when you treat the element 4, but that index is one beyond the limit of your array. (The numbers you saw were just garbage from uninitialised elements in `B`.)

By the way, decreasing first when counting down is a frequent thing in C, which is owed to the fact that upper bounds of arrays are exclusive. Your loop could have been written like this:

```
for (i = n; i-- > 0; ) {
    C[A[i]] = C[A[i]] - 1;
    B[C[A[i]]] = A[i];
}
```

The update part is missing, because the decrement happens before the loop body is entered. And you get away without subtracting one in the initialisation.